# Can a factory unlocked iPhone 5 be used with Sprint?

Tags: unlock, cellular-carriers

If I were to buy a brand new factory unlocked iPhone off eBay would I then be able to use that phone on sprint?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if the device is UNLOCKED it can be used with any carrier in the world.